# Possibly broken azure-search tokenizer - PathHierarchyTokenizerV2

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Lately, I wanted to take advantage of a field on my search index that uses a custom analyzer with the PathHierarchyTokenizerV2 tokenizer.

this same index used to work, and the custom analyzer did break the text into the correct path segments when using the "Analyzer Test" API.

i.e. the text `l1/l2/l3` turns into:
`l1`,
`l1/l2`,
`l1/l2/l3`,

At the moment, it seems like this functionality no longer works. Or, am I doing something wrong?

I reproduce by creating an index with the following field:

```
{
    "name": "tags",
    "type": "Edm.String",
    "searchable": true,
    "filterable": true,
    "retrievable": true,
    "sortable": false,
    "facetable": true,
    "key": false,
    "indexAnalyzer": null,
    "searchAnalyzer": null,
    "analyzer": "categoryPathAnalyzer",
    "synonymMaps": []
}
```

Where `categoryPathAnalyzer` is defined as:

```
   {
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "name": "categoryPathAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer": "path_hierarchy_v2",
      "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase"
      ],
      "charFilters": []
    }
```

The "Analyzer Test" API is [called](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) with the following body:

```
{
  "text": "a/b",
  "analyzer": "categoryPathAnalyzer"
}
```

And the result is empty:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://x.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01_Preview.AnalyzeResult",
    "tokens": []
}
```

If it matters, this index and calls are all using the latest `2016-09-01-Preview` API version.

Comment: I am Nate from Azure Search. We are looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this. We found a bug in the built-in path_hierarchy_v2 tokenizer. The bug has been fixed. Please let us know if the issue persists.